# Black Universal Joints

Tags: technic, colour, customization, 3d-printing

I'm seeking ***black*** universal joints for a project. Do these exist in genuine LEGO form? I'm guessing the answer is no, despite hints ([here](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=9244c01&colorID=11) and [here](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-black-universal-joint-4)). Ideally, I'd like the 3L size.

- Do you know of a non-LEGO source that sells black u-joints?
- Do you know if [dying](https://www.brothers-brick.com/2013/06/30/50-shades-of-bley-iain-heaths-mad-lego-science/) the standard gray LEGO u-joints black is possible, especially given that these parts are relatively small and complex?
- Do you know if any rapid manufacturing process, e.g., 3D printing, could produce a nice u-joint?

Comment: They don't show up as black in any inventory, but that doesn't rule their existence out. But they do seem unlikely to be available by the usual not-in-set means (test bricks, Pick-a-Brick wall, etc.). As far as coloring, I'd think it'd be a lot easier to dye (or paint) something light to be black instead of the other way around.

Comment: I'd also recommend searching for "build your own lego universal joint" - some of the solutions may be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @RSchulz I don't see why you couldn't post your comments as an answer.

Comment: Don't think painting UJ's is a good idea, the hinge points are rather small and paint likely would add friction there or glue the hinge points fixed...

Comment: @RSchulz I don’t think a build-your-own would work for my project. I’m looking for the 3L u-joint specifically.

Comment: @Alex I appreciate the note of confidence, but I was hoping someone would have something positive and more helpful to say. Mine is all speculation and doom and gloom. And I agree with (no at allowed) Michael Verschaeve that this part seems like the worst case scenario for painting.

Answer (score 1):

There is one on [thingiverse](https://thingiverse.com/thing:3399986). I haven't tried it.

[image: 3-D printed universal joint]